# Does 'Cache-Control: No-cache' support this setting?

Tags: javascript, html, caching, http-caching

Does  'Cache-Control: No-cache'  support  this  setting?

"Cache-Control: no-cache" is cached but invalidated immediately, then go to cdn to compare etag. If the etag has not expired, cdn returns 304 to use the local cache, and when it expires, it returns 202 to use the new online content.

The current scene:
Go to cdn to compare etag, but the network is disconnected. At this time, the local cache is used instead of reporting network errors. How should it be implemented? 
Mobile Browser support?  How to set?

Comment: Have you checked `s-maxage` ?

Comment: when you have a network, go to cdn to compare etag.    s-maxage set to be cdn cache, no network will report error?      Cache-Control: no-cache, s-maxage=2592000  this setting?